# Why do VPC endpoints not support Amazon RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I want to execute AWS CLI commands of RDS not via the internet, but via a VPC network for mainly creating manual snapshots of RDS.

However, VPC endpoints support only RDS Data API according to the following document:

[VPC endpoints - Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html)

Why? I need to execute a command within closed network for security rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to reiterate you can still connect to your RDS database through the normal private network using whichever library you choose to perform any DDL, DML, DCL and TCL commands. Although in your case you want to create a snapshot which is via the service endpoint.

VPC endpoints are to connect to the **service APIs** that power AWS (think the interactions you perform in the console, SDK or CLI), at the moment this means for RDS to create, modify or delete resources  you need to use the API over the public internet (using HTTPS for encrypted traffic).

VPC endpoints are **added over time**, just because a specific API is not there now does not mean it will never be there. There is an integration that has to be carried out by the team of that AWS service to allow VPC endpoints to work.

Comment: Wonderful update has come! https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/07/amazon-rds-application-programming-interface-supports-aws-privatelink/